# defining a singelton per client variable in web-development bll

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I'm looking for a design\pattern to my problem.

I want to declare a singleton variable in a web-development environment, 
but I want it to be singleton per user per session.

i.e. MyClass.StaticVar will be initialized once for each client per session 
and be globally accessible to that client.

What would you suggest?
What are all the caching options\levels possible in web-application BLL layer (I understand we can use Session dictionary only in aspx and ascx code behind. right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do something like:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass StaticVar
    {
        get
        {
            var s = HttpContext.Current.Session["MyClass"] as MyClass;
            if ( s==null )
            {
                s = new MyClass();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["MyClass"] = s;
            }

            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

You may add locking (`lock` statement) in the above example to make it thread-safe.

Comment: Session is available at any layer? not just aspx and ascx code behind?

Comment: You would need to pass the singleton instance inward to the next class when calling constructors from your CodeBehind